# what is the difference between [=] vs [this]?

Tags: c++, c++17

In some project found fix like this:

```
-        use([=](Foo* &df) {
+        use([this](Foo* &df) {
             delete df;
             df = nullptr;
         });
```

where `use` is:

```
        template<class LAMBDA>
        void use(LAMBDA callback) {
            LOCK lock(this->mutex);
            callback(this->data);
        }
```

What is going on here, why `[=]` and `[this]` make difference?
Is `this` just a pointer, so it should be copied by value and `[=]` should be equivalent to `[this]`,
or with `[=]` the object which is pointed to by `this` is copied by value?

Comment: Why does it capture anything at all? It seems to just operate on the argument.

Comment: For this lambda the change doesn't make sense, because `this` isn't used. If it was used, the explanation could be that in C++20, the automatic capture of `this` by `=` is deprecated (I guess because it would make more sense for it to capture `*this` by value instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not a variable (it is a keyword). As such, normal rules of capturing variables don't apply. Both capture-defaults & and = capture the object pointed by `this` i.e. `*this` by reference. Since C++20, the implicit capture of `*this` when using = capture-default is deprecated.

The obvious difference between using capture-default versus `this` is that former implicitly captures any local variables used in the lambda while the latter does not.

In the case of the shown lambda, it doesn't appear to use any captures, so any capture declaration appears to be redundant.